# Parent DIV height problem

Tags: css, css-float

When I give float:left and float:right to inner divs. The height property of their parent div doesn't works. Why? How to solve?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSW5G/1/) to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give `overflow: auto;` in parent div. This will handle the height difference between parent and child.

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSW5G/2/)

Answer (score 6):

Add this line before the closing of parent div

```
<br style="clear:both"/>
```

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/CSW5G/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Harry's right. For completeness: floating the parent also works, as does adding a cleared element (or pseudo-element) at the bottom.